# Как отсортировать картинки на php?

Tags: php

Есть функция `search_img()` на `php`, которая выводит все картинки из папки, картинки выводятся по названию (`1.jpg, 2,jpg, 3.jpg` и так далее). Как можно отсортировать картинки по дате загрузки на `php` ?

Php:

```
function search_img($path)
{
    $html = "";
    foreach (glob($path . "*{.jpg,.gif,.png}", GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {
        $html .= '<img class="pimg" src="' . $filename . '" />';
    }
    return $html;
}

echo search_img("uploads/");
```

Css:

```
.pimg{
    width:140px;
    max-height:100px;
    float:left; 
    margin: 10px;
    background-color:#fff;  
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding:4px;    
    border-radius:4px;              
    -moz-border-radius:4px;      
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;  
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0, .5);
    cursor: pointer;    
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример, как можно отсортировать массив по ключам (key это время, а value это название картинки).

```
function search_img($path){ 
      $html="";
    foreach (glob($path."*{jpg,gif,png}", GLOB_BRACE) as $filename){
        $file[filemtime($filename)] = $filename ;
    }   
    krsort($file);  //Сортировка
    reset($file);

    foreach ($file as $k => $v){
        // echo "Key : $k; Valuе : $v <br />\n";   
        $html .= '<img class="pimg" src="'.$v.'" />';
    }   
      return $html;
}
```

Применение:

```
echo search_img("uploads/");
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно пройтись по каждой картинки, вытащить ее дату создания и отсортирвоать по ней.

Примерно так:

```
function sortFilesByDateCreation($files) {
    $filesWithDates = Array();
    foreach($files as $file) {
        $filesWithDates[$file] = filemtime([ABS_FILES_PATH] . $file);
    }
    asort($filesWithDates);
    return array_keys($pictWithDates);
}
```

- Если надо сортировать в обратном порядке, то вместо `asort()`
  используйте `arsort()`
- Вам может понадобиться поставить абсолютный путь к файлам: `[ABS_FILES_PATH]`